# Can I use a requirements.txt file to handle local python directories?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I've got a directory structure like this:

```
src/
--scripts/
----foo/a.py
----bar/b.py
--lib1
--lib2
--lib3
```

The intent if to have scripts/foo/ and scripts/bar/ be directories of runnable python scripts that make use of the modules in lib1, lib2, lib3. Scripts, lib1, lib2, and lib3 are all separate internal git repositories under active development. There isn't a static interface or published version to depend on. Basically, they are all being written nearly at the same time by a small team.

I've played with making lib[1-3] submodules and I really hate the workflow. What I think I would like is to be able to do "import lib1" from foo/a.py and have it use the current code in lib1. Once things mature we will likely version everything and work to product proper packages.

One way to do this would to muck with `sys.path` in each of the scripts to explicitly look in '../../' or something. I was wondering if there was something more elegant. Could I get something like `pip install -r requirements.txt` to do this work for me? I don't want to make an official pypi setup.py, I just want to get a pointer to the current contents of the lib[1-3] directory. The reason I like the requirements.txt approach is that as the libs mature, I'll end up putting version and git URLs in there.

Or, is there a completely different way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing a module from a git repository in the usual ways *does* require a `setup.py`, but it can be a bare minimum one rather than a fuller one like you'd use for a PyPI module. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name="foo",
)
```

If you drop something like that into each of your lib repositories then you can make your requirements file point to the git repo using `-e git://git.example.com/foo.git#egg=foo`. If you install this into a virtualenv then it will appear at `src/foo` inside the virtualenv directory, and it'll be added to `sys.path` automatically when running Python from that virtualenv.

The `-e` option also accepts a local directory as a parameter, so if you guarantee that the current working directory will always be the root of your project when you install from `requirements.txt` (so that the relative path resolves correctly) it should work just fine to write things like `-e lib1` in there, and then you can still reference the libraries as git submodules if you want.

If you are determined *not* to create a `setup.py` then your task is to emulate what would happen when running `python setup.py develop`. This command does two things (as of Python 2.7, at least):

- It creates an [egg link](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/doc/formats.txt) in the `site-packages` lib directory in your virtualenv (or system-wide if you don't have a virtualenv) that points to your target source directory.
- It adds a line to `easy-install.pth`, which is also in the `site-packages` directory, which also points to your target source directory.

You could choose to do both of the above actions by a means other than running `setup.py editable` and get the same effect for current versions of Python, but of course the implementation of editable distributions may change in newer versions of Python.

Comment: If I'm not using virtualenv, where will it install?

Comment: If you're installing from a git repo, in my experience `pip` will make a `src` directory in the current working directory. I'm not sure if that's intentional or just a bug that results from the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable not being set. If you install from a local directory then it will just try to write the egg link and the `pth` file into the system-wide `site-packages` dir, with the absolute path to the local directory you indicated.